# Trigger python code from Google spreadsheets?

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In excel you can create user defined functions with python using `pyxll`. I have been moving to Google spreadsheets and using their Google app script, but the libraries are so much bigger and better in python, I wish there was a way to build user defined functions using python from Google spreadsheets. There are ways to interact python with Google sheets like `gspread`. Is there a way to run python on Google app engine then get sheet to trigger that code? What other ways is there to trigger python code from Google spreadsheets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to have some code that reads the spreadsheet all the time, then runs some other code when a condition is met.

Without GAE, you could use the following code:

```
#http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/downloads/list
import gdata.spreadsheet.service as s

spreadsheet_key = 'spreadsheetkey'# https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=<spreadsheet key>&usp=sharing#gid=0

worksheet_key = 'od6' #first tab
gd_client = s.SpreadsheetsService(spreadsheet_key, worksheet_key)
gd_client.email = 'user@gmail.com'
gd_client.password = 'password'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
list_feed = gd_client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_key, worksheet_key)
for entry in list_feed.entry:
    #read cell values and then do something if the condition is met
```

If you wanted to have the spreadsheet run code in a GAE app, then you could publish the spreadsheet and construct the URL of the spreadsheet (JSON) like this: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/(spreadsheetkey)/od6/public/values?alt=json
This address can be accessed via the app, the cell values can be read, and some code can be triggered.

The approach is the same with both ideas: some code monitors the spreadsheet and when some condition is met, some other code is triggered. I'm not sure how you could run the code (in a GAE app, say) when the condition is met purely from the Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 9):

You should create a webservice in GAE which then can be called using Google Apps Script `UrlFetch` class. 
This is how I usually do to integrate a third party app with Apps Script App.

In a Spreadsheet container script you can create a code like

```
function myFunction(){
  //your code
  //Call the webservice
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('my_webservice_url', {payload:'...', method:'POST'});
 Logger.log(response.getContentText());
 // your code based on response
}
```

Above code can be triggered by a time driven trigger in Apps Script based on some conditions

Answer (score 7):

Deploy your python code as a cloud function:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http.

Then call your function with URL Fetch as shown above.

Comment: saved my day! Took literally less than 5 min. Just be careful to not accidentally do: pip install google-cloud-storage. (Which is in the first steps guide). This made an error while deploying to gcloud.

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN USE `APP SCRYPT` TO SAVE A FILE IN GOOGLE DRIVE FOLDER
[Upload file to my google drive with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374794/upload-file-to-my-google-drive-with-google-apps-script-no-form-in-google)

and use python to watch a folder in you computer with google drive desktop sync with this folder
Use [Google Drive Desktop](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) to syncfolder of drive in you computer
and
Use [Watch Python](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) to observe this folder