# Launching Python script from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, python, google-apps-script

I've been searching for some time, and, as I couldn't find an answer, I'm asking this one. My issue is quite simple:

I have a form linked to a sheet. Bound to this sheet, I have a script running, performing calculations based on the just inserted data, and taking actions. Although, I would like to perform a request on a given API. For so, I have a working script in python (something about 100 lines), and I'm not willing to rewrite it in JS (and I don't even know if that would be possible, considering some limitations on Google Apps Script JS), nor do I want to pay for Google App Engine.

Is there anyway to run an external file, like a DOS command line, from my script in Google Apps Script?

I've seen something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926456/trigger-python-code-from-google-spreadsheets), but this doesn't fit my cases because the asker is willing to use GAE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: GAE has a free tier, if you didn't know.

Comment: Oh, thanks, @MattDMo , I really didn't! 
But, by that, you mean the trial 60 days version?

Comment: I have a couple apps running on GAE that I wrote several years ago, that I've never paid a cent for. AFAIK, you can still do that. Search through the docs, download the SDK, and see what you can do.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll either have to run the python app in a 3rd party service and then call it from GAS using UrlFetch(); or call a GAS function from python using Google's [execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api). I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: I understand, and pitty on that. Thank you!