# How to run a Python Script from a Google Sheet

Tags: python, google-apps-script, gspread

I have a Python script that leverages lists in a Google Sheet and sends bulk SMS text messages using Twilio.

I'm fairly new to this and have struggled to get this far - any Python script I've created in the past, I've been able to just run off my local computer in VS Code.

I am trying to share this with a family member - I've read into tkinter and gui's a bit, but because the rest of this workflow is already in a Google Sheet, it would be perfect if any user could just run the Python script right from the spreadsheet itself.

I found this, but I don't really understand how to create a webservice in GAE.  I've googled it all over but struggling to put into action --  [Trigger python code from Google spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926456/trigger-python-code-from-google-spreadsheets)

Is there a simple way to just tie my Python script into this spreadsheet so that anyone can run it? Or another way to go about this?

ChatGPT response says this, but I feel it is inaccurate (or I just can't get it working):

[image: ChatGPT Response]

My code is here, if it helps:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import gspread

# Your Account SID and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = 'AC868ea4e1a779ff0816b466a13f201b02'
auth_token = '85469ae1eb492ffc814c095b5c6e0889'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')

# Open a spreadsheet by ID
sh = gc.open_by_key('1KRYITQ_O_-7exPZp8zj1VvAUPPutqtO4SrTgloCx8x4')

# Get the sheets
wk = sh.worksheet("Numbers to Send")

# E.G. the URLs are listed on Sheet 1 on Column A
numbers = wk.batch_get(('f3:f',))[0]
names = wk.batch_get(('g3:g',))[0]

# names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Jim']
# numbers = ['+16099725052', '+16099725052', '+16099725052']

# Loop through the names and numbers and send a text message to each phone number
for i in range(len(names)):

    message = client.messages.create(
        to=numbers[i],
        from_='+18442251378',
        body=f"Hello {names[i][0]}, this is a test message from Twilio.")
    print(f"Message sent to {names[i]} at {numbers[i]}")
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `How to run a Python Script from a Google Sheet`, when I saw your question, I cannot understand when you want to execute the python script from Google Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detailed situation for executing your python script from Google Spreadsheet? And, can I ask you about the detailed reason that you are required to use python script?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike - ideally, I could have a button on my Google Sheet that triggers the Python script, similar to as if I were triggering an Apps Script file.  I'm not required to use Python at all, it just took me a long time to figure out how to get my Python script working (above).. didn't want to try to recreate it if I didn't have to.  Doing the same function in Apps Script would work - I'll start looking into how I might be able to do that.  I was hoping I could just share this script with someone else so they can run it via Google Sheets

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to run a script by some actions in Google Spreadsheet, I thought that Google Apps Script is suitable. But from `I was hoping I could just share this script with someone else so they can run it via Google Sheets`, if you want to run a script except for Google Apps Script by some actions in Google Spreadsheet, I thought that the HTTP request might be required to be run by Google Apps Script. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike this is very helpful - I'm not entirely understanding how I could set this up though? I essentially have a Python script on my local computer that I want to make available to any Google Sheets user (they can run it there).  Does that make sense at all? Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to run the script in your local PC from Google Apps Script, I think that it is required to prepare a server in your local PC and it is required to be able to be accessed from the HTTP request by Google Apps Script. I think that in this case, it might be a bit complicated. If you can use Google Apps Script instead of another language, I would like to recommend using it. In that case, other users can also use the Google Apps Script.