# Driving a colab python script from Google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

Here is what I need to do.

1. Populate a drop down list from a python function in `colab`.
2. Allow user to select one item and after hitting go fire another python function.

I can write and read from a Google Sheets from colab, but I have no way to drive python this way. I cannot seem to find any examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger python code from Google spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926456/trigger-python-code-from-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: @GiselleValladares I would like to use google colab for "hosting" or running the python.