# Running a Google Colab script from Google Sheets? (App Script)

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I have a snippet of code in python that integrates with a google sheet using gspread.

I'd love to be able to call this code from the sheet itself by assigning an App Script to a button.

I believe I've searched extensively but the meager answers I found are a bit too complex beyond my beginner comprehension.

Any help is appreciated!

I did set up Google Colab to upload my python script to the cloud. Able to run it smoothly but still in the dark on any possible way to call this script through Google Sheets.

The top answer in this thread:

[Trigger python code from Google spreadsheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926456/trigger-python-code-from-google-spreadsheets)

is still a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Does colab provide a api to call it? The top answer in that thread provides a alternative - to use Google cloud functions, an another service by Google.

Comment: searching on stackoverflow the answer seems to be that it'd be the google drive API but I don't know how to run code that is in colab

Comment: Seems you can't. Use Google cloud functions instead.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way?

Comment: no i did not find a way